# trigger an event from another control

Tags: vb.net, raiseevent

I'm using vb.net and winform. I am coming across an issue which I'm pounding my head against for the past few hours.

I have a main usercontrol which I added a groupbox and inside that groupbox, added a control like this:

main usercontrol

```
Me.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Me.ctlWithDropDown)
```

user control ctlWithDropDown

```
Me.Controls.Add(Me.ddList)

Private Sub ddlList_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlList.SelectionChanged
'some simple logic here to check if value changed        

End Sub
```

The main usercontrol inherits the base class which has an event to set a value to true or false like so:

```
 Public Event SetFlag(ByVal value As Boolean)
```

I want to know how I can trigger/set this boolean value from the dropdownlist when the SelectionChanged event is trigger. Any help on this issue?

Comment: use RaiseEvent in a handler for selectedchanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wire up an event handler for the drop down list:

```
AddHandler Me.ctlDropDown.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ddlSelectedIndexChanged
Me.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Me.ctlDropDown)
```

Make sure you create ddlSelectedIndexChanged in your control and have it fire the SetFlag Event:

```
Protected Sub ddlSelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

   RaiseEvent SetFlag(True)

End Sub
```

Comment: I've updated a little bit more info. Can you clearify which to put on the main usercontrol and what to put on the user control ctlWithDropDown. I'm at lost here.

Comment: Your edit has confused me some.  Please explain your issue and code structure a little better and I will edit.

Comment: it's more like a user control on a user control. The first user control holds a second user control which has a drop down list. The first user control inherits the parent which has an event call SetFlag(boolean). On the second user control, when the drop down list's event "SelectionChanged" is fired, I want to raise the event SetFlag(boolean). How would I do this?

Comment: never mind, your suggestion worked. I never used Raising Events before so I was just a bit confuse. But it's all working now. thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I presume the me.ctlDropDown is something that you are making programmatically? If so then this sort of thing should work for you.

```
Public Sub Blah()
    Dim ctlDropDown As New ComboBox
    AddHandler ctlDropDown.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf IndexChangedHandler
    Me.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(ctlDropDown)
End Sub

Private Sub IndexChangedHandler()
    'Do whatever you need here.
End Sub
```

However, if this is not created at runtime should make an event handler like:

```
Private Sub IndexChangedHandler() Handles Me.ctlDropdown.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Do whatever you need here.
End Sub
```